# How to stop a cycle in a frame?

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I've made an animation with a cycle modifier in GraphEditor. I just want to stop the cycle in a frame and animate another action.

Comment: Hello, in the Noise modifier for example you have a Restrict Frame Range option, enable it and choose the frame start and end